# How to transform negative elements to zero without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array like

```
a = np.array([2, 3, -1, -4, 3])
```

I want to set all the negative elements to zero: `[2, 3, 0, 0, 3]`. How to do it with numpy without an explicit for? I need to use the modified `a` in a computation, for example

```
c = a * b
```

where `b` is another array with the same length of the original `a`

## Conclusion

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)
t = time(); b = np.where(a>0, a, 0); print ("1. ", time() - t)
a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)
t = time(); b = a.clip(min=0); print ("2. ", time() - t)
a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)
t = time(); a[a < 0] = 0; print ("3. ", time() - t)
a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)
t = time(); a[np.where(a<0)] = 0; print ("4. ", time() - t)
a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)
t = time(); b = [max(x, 0) for x in a]; print ("5. ", time() - t)
```

1. 1.38629984856
2. 0.516846179962      <- faster a.clip(min=0);
3. 0.615426063538
4. 0.944557905197
5. 51.7364809513

Comment: On my machine `a[a < 0] = 0` is significantly faster than `a.clip(min=0)`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
a = a.clip(min=0)
```

Comment: It might be.  You'll have to test them to see which is fastest.  I don't use numpy a lot, so I'm not sure, though numpy is supposed to be very well optimized, so it could well outperform my answers.

Comment: wiso, I think you found the fastest way.
`%timeit a.clip(min=0,out=a)` took 5.65 microseconds per loop.
`%timeit np.where(a>0,a,0)` took 24 microseconds per loop,
`%timeit a[a<0]=0` took 11.6 microseconds per loop.

Comment: One can also use `np.clip(lst, a_min=0, a_max=None)` for python lists.

Answer (score 26):

I would do this:

```
a[a < 0] = 0
```

If you want to keep the original `a` and only set the negative elements to zero in a copy, you can copy the array first:

```
c = a.copy()
c[c < 0] = 0
```

Answer (score 16):

Another trick is to use multiplication. This actually seems to be much faster than every other method here. For example

```
b = a*(a>0) # copies data
```

or

```
a *= (a>0) # in-place zero-ing
```

I ran tests with timeit, pre-calculating the the < and > because some of these modify in-place and that would greatly effect results. In all cases `a` was `np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 20000000)` but with negatives already set to 0 but `L = a < 0` and `G = a > 0` before `a` was changed. The `clip` is relatively negatively impacted since it doesn't get to use `L` or `G` (however calculating those on the same machine took only 17ms each, so it is not the major cause of speed difference).

```
%timeit b = np.where(G, a, 0)  # 132ms  copies
%timeit b = a.clip(min=0)      # 165ms  copies
%timeit a[L] = 0               # 158ms  in-place
%timeit a[np.where(L)] = 0     # 122ms  in-place
%timeit b = a*G                # 87.4ms copies
%timeit np.multiply(a,G,a)     # 40.1ms in-place (normal code would use `a*=G`)
```

When choosing to penalize the in-place methods instead of `clip`, the following timings come up:

```
%timeit b = np.where(a>0, a, 0)             # 152ms
%timeit b = a.clip(min=0)                   # 165ms
%timeit b = a.copy(); b[a<0] = 0            # 231ms
%timeit b = a.copy(); b[np.where(a<0)] = 0  # 205ms
%timeit b = a*(a>0)                         # 108ms
%timeit b = a.copy(); b*=a>0                # 121ms
```

Non in-place methods are penalized by 20ms (the time required to calculate `a>0` or `a<0`) and the in-place methods are penalize 73-83 ms (so it takes about 53-63ms to do `b.copy()`).

Overall the multiplication methods are much faster than `clip`. If not in-place, it is **1.5x** faster. If you can do it in-place then it is **2.75x** faster.

Comment: To use precomputed quantities means cheating

Comment: But they all (but one) use pre-computed values. And the calculations that were pre-computed are fast, taking 17ms on the same machine under same conditions, so they aren't the cause of the speed difference. And if I didn't pre-compute them then the in-place methods would look way faster since after the first attempt there would be nothing to zero-out.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra Added more comparisons. I hope you think this is more fair. Instead of penalizing `clip` I penalized the in-place methods. It does show that multiplication is still much faster than clip.

Comment: On my machine: `timeit.timeit('a *= (a>0)', number = 100000, setup='import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,90000); a=a.reshape((300,300))')` takes **9.1 seconds** (`a=a*(a>0)` takes 10.1), while `timeit.timeit('a = a.clip(min=0)', number = 100000, setup='import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,90000); a=a.reshape((300,300))')` only takes **4.3 s**. With `a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,900000000); a=a.reshape((30000,30000))` as setup, a single execution takes 1.79s, 3.44s and 2.18s resp. **Conclusion:** Use `a.clip` for small arrays and `a*=(a<0)` for large arrays, if in-place is ok

Comment: The inplace timings you presented above will modify the value of `a`
in the first run – affecting the performance of the subsequent calls.
A correct and fair timing must do an additional copy of `a` for *every* method.
Note also that the result depends on the ratio of negative numbers.
With 10% negative numbers and inlining `L=(a<0)` and `G=(a>0)` rather
than precomputing them, I have `124ms / 98ms / 122ms / 111ms / 124ms /
143ms` as in your first timing, i.e. `clip` is the fastest
and inplace is useless performancewise. https://gist.github.com/coldfix/7e0bfb82b4ff80761e37937eb86752e0

Answer (score 7):

Use [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
a[numpy.where(a<0)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70923548/11671779), using np.maximum is the fastest possible way.

```py
a = np.random.random(1000) - 0.5

%%timeit
a_ = a.copy()
a_ = np.maximum(a_,0)
# 15.6 µs ± 2.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%%timeit
a_ = a.copy()
a_ = a_.clip(min=0)
# 54.2 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for the sake of comprehensiveness, I would like to add the use of the Heaviside function (or a step function) to achieve a similar outcome as follows:

Let say for continuity we have

```
a = np.array([2, 3, -1, -4, 3])
```

Then using a step function [`np.heaviside()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html) one can try

```
b = a * np.heaviside(a, 0)
```

Note something interesting in this operation because the negative signs are preserved! Not very ideal for most situations I would say.

This can then be corrected for by

```
b = abs(b)
```

So this is probably a rather long way to do it without invoking some loop.