# Replace negative values in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way of replacing all negative values in an array with 0?

I'm having a complete block on how to do it using a NumPy array.

E.g.

```
a = array([1, 2, 3, -4, 5])
```

I need to return

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
```

`a < 0` gives:

```
[False, False, False, True, False]
```

This is where I'm stuck - how to use this array to modify the original array.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You are halfway there. Try:

```
In [4]: a[a < 0] = 0

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

Comment: Benchmark and faster solution (according to my benchmark) can be seen [on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70923548/11671779)

Answer (score 101):

Try `numpy.clip`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(-10, 10)
>>> a
array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,
         3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9])
>>> a.clip(0, 10)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

You can clip only the bottom half with `clip(0)`.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, -4, 5])
>>> a.clip(0)
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

You can clip only the top half with `clip(max=n)`. (This is much better than my previous suggestion, which involved passing `NaN` to the first parameter and using `out` to coerce the type.):

```
>>> a.clip(max=2)
array([ 1,  2,  2, -4,  2])
```

Another interesting approach is to use `where`:

```
>>> numpy.where(a <= 2, a, 2)
array([ 1,  2,  2, -4,  2])
```

Finally, consider [aix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335159/577088)'s answer. I prefer `clip` for simple operations because it's self-documenting, but his answer is preferable for more complex operations.

Comment: a.clip(0) would suffice since the OP just wants to replace negative values. a.clip(0, 10) would exclude anything above 10.

Comment: @Hiett - I just tried it and clip will take one. First is assumed min.

Comment: must be a version issue with numpy - heres my ouptut: (Pdb) np.clip(w,0)
*** TypeError: clip() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) - whereas: (Pdb) np.clip(w,0,1e6)
array([[ 0.   ,  0.605]])

Comment: @Hiett, what version of `numpy`? Did you try the clip _method_ of `a`? The built-in function `numpy.clip` gives me the same error, but the method does not.

Comment: yeh if you call it that way round it seems to work, e.g. p w.clip(0)
array([[ 0.   ,  0.605]]) - how queer?

Comment: @senderle, I think you're looking for `a.clip(max=2)`

Answer (score 10):

Another minimalist Python solution without using numpy:

```
[0 if i < 0 else i for i in a]
```

No need to define any extra functions.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, -4, -5.23, 6]
[0 if i < 0 else i for i in a]
```

yields:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6]
```

Comment: that is nice - i was wondering what the syntax would be to put the if statement inside the list comprehension - i was going wrong by sticking it after the for loop and only then getting two values back, e.g. [0, 0] for your example list

Comment: I did the same when I originally learned about list comprehension and was trying out different things to test my understanding - it seemed more intuitive to put it after the for loop for me too. Now, though, this does :)  Putting it before the `for` applies it to every element of the list, putting it after, means only if the condition is met does it go into the resulting list.

Comment: @Hiett It's just using the ternary operator (`i < 0 ? 0 : i` in C) inside a list comprehension. Put brackets in to make it clearer `[(0 if i < 0 else i) for i in a]`. Putting the if after is using the filter part of the list expression construct. `[(i) for i in a if i < 0]` will only return a list of items that are less than zero.

Comment: Numpy is powerful because it does a lot of the computation by compiled c code and is thus faster.  Comparing this method to the others, I find almost a 10 times speed factor difference (this is slower).  So while intuitive and easy to read, this is definitely not for the computationally intensive.

Answer (score 4):

And yet another possibility:

```
In [2]: a = array([1, 2, 3, -4, 5])

In [3]: where(a<0, 0, a)
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in Python without NumPy. Create a function that returns what you want and use a list comprehension, or the [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, -4, 5]

>>> def zero_if_negative(x):
...   if x < 0:
...     return 0
...   return x
...

>>> [zero_if_negative(x) for x in a]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]

>>> map(zero_if_negative, a)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
```

Comment: had gone down this route but thought there must be an easier, more matlab less python way to do it with numpy (as i was using arrays rather than lists anyway). clip is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Benchmark using `numpy`:

```
%%timeit
a = np.random.random(1000) - 0.5
b = np.maximum(a,0)
# 18.2 µs ± 204 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
a = np.random.random(1000) - 0.5
a[a < 0] = 0
# 19.6 µs ± 304 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
a = np.random.random(1000) - 0.5
b = np.where(a<0, 0, a)
# 21.1 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
a = np.random.random(1000) - 0.5
b = a.clip(0)
# 37.7 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Supprisingly, `np.maximum` beat [@NPE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335159/11671779).

---

Caveat:

1. `os[os < 0] = 0` is faster than `np.where()` but not supported by `numba`. But whatever, `np.maximum()` is the fastest that I found.
2. `np.maximum()` is different from `np.max()` and `np.amax()`. `np.maximum()` can compare `vector` with single value.