# Using arctan / arctan2 to plot a from 0 to 2π

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to replicate a plot in *Orbital Mechanics* by Curtis, but I just can't quite get it. However, I have made head way by switching to `np.arctan2` from `np.arctan`.

Maybe I am implementing `arctan2` incorrectly?

```
import pylab
import numpy as np

e = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.15).reshape(-1, 1)

nu = np.linspace(0.001, 2 * np.pi - 0.001, 50000)
M2evals = (2 * np.arctan2(1, 1 / (((1 - e) / (1 + e)) ** 0.5 * np.tan(nu / 2) -
           e * (1 - e ** 2) ** 0.5 * np.sin(nu) / (1 + e * np.cos(nu)))))

fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

for Me2, _e in zip(M2evals, e.ravel()):
    ax2.plot(nu.ravel(), Me2, label = str(_e))

pylab.legend()
pylab.xlim((0, 7.75))
pylab.ylim((0, 2 * np.pi))
pylab.show()
```

In the image below, there are discontinuities popping up. The function is supposed to be smooth and connect at 0 and 2 pi in the y range of (0, 2pi) not touching 0 and 2pi.

[image]

Textbook plot and equation:

[image]

[image]

At the request of Saullo Castro, I was told that:

> The problem may lie in the arctan function which gives "principle values" as output.

Thus, arctan(tan(x)) does not yield x if x is an angle in the second or third quadrant. If you plot arctan(tan(x)) from x = 0 to x = Pi, you will find that it has a discontinuous jump at x = Pi/2.

For your case, instead of writing arctan(arg), I believe you would write arctan2(1, 1/arg) where arg is the argument of your arctan function. That way, when arg becomes negative, arctan2 will yield an angle in the second quadrant rather than the fourth."

Comment: To use arctan2 correctly, you need an equation for x, and an equation for y.  The whole point of arctan2 is that the ratio y/x is ambiguous about the quadrant: -/- == +/+ and -/+ == +/-.  If you put in y as a constant, you can still only occupy two quadrants in the result.  So what you're saying doesn't make sense: this can't both be the equation and fill the quadrants you say.  (Since all you're saying now is "I have this equation and it doesn't work", we don't have enough info to answer this and it's not a question that can be answered.)

Comment: @tom10 it very close to working if we take out .6 - .9, the solution is correct.  It is breaking down above .6 but maybe lower since the range is by .15

Comment: Still, you're not giving people enough information, I'd like to know where you going, not where you started.  "Close to correct" is not particularly helpful.  This doesn't seem to be a question about acrtan2, but a question about what's in your textbook.

Comment: @tom10 adding pics of the equation and plot then.

Comment: great! note that in the equation from the textbook, the arctan is only over the first term, not the whole equation.

Comment: @tom10 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Look at the parenthesis directly right of tan^-1, where's the matching parenthesis.  It's after the tan(theta/2), not at the end of the whole equation.  In your equation, you're doing the arctan of the whole thing.

Comment: I agree with @tom10, it seems like a case of a misplaced closing paren.  Or two.

Comment: This question should just be closed, imho.  It's just a parenthesis typo on the part of the OP, and sheds no light on anything else (especially not arctan vs arctan2 due to the misdirection).  Therefore, closed as "too localized".

Comment: @tom10 well I did learn how to moved the legend from it so it was helpful.

Comment: @tom10 The question should not be closed. It brings a very common problem into discussion and it suggests to use arctan2() to avoid summing 2*pi for the negatives obtained with arctan()

Comment: @SaultoCastro: it only brings that in tangentially (ha ha).  If you want that to be what this question is about, then I suggest you answer it, with pictures of the domains, explain why arctan2(1,1/x) works, which is better, etc.  Instead you're just asking others to answer that, while you've actually answered what the question is really about... making a figure that exactly matches the one in the OP's text book (ie, it's way too localized). (btw, I'm outa here... this has been a total waste of time.)

Comment: This is too localized as the actual problem (and correct answer) involves neither `python`, `numpy`, nor `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common practice is to sum 2*pi in the negative results of `arctan()`, [which can be done efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335090/numpy-replace-negative-values-in-array/10335159#10335159). The OP's suggestion to replace arctan(x) by arctan2(1, 1/x), also suggested by Maple 15's documentation as [pointed out by Yay295](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613546/using-arctan-arctan2-to-plot-a-from-0-to-2%CF%80#comment79235056_16614914), produces the same results without the need to sum 2*pi. Both are shown below:

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
e = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.15).reshape(-1, 1)
nu = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50000)
x =  ((1-e)/(1+e))**0.5 * np.tan(nu/2.)
x2 = e*(1-e**2)**0.5 * np.sin(nu)/(1 + e*np.cos(nu))
using_arctan = True
using_OP_arctan2 = False

if using_arctan:
    M2evals = 2*np.arctan(x) - x2
    M2evals[M2evals<0] += 2*np.pi
elif using_OP_arctan2:
    M2evals = 2 * np.arctan2(1,1/x) - x2

fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
for M2e, _e in zip(M2evals, e.ravel()):
    ax2.plot(nu.ravel(), M2e, label = str(_e))
pylab.legend(loc='upper left')
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Using arctan2(1, 1/x) instead of arctan(x) here is just ridiculous.

Comment: @tom10 I see your point, originally I suggested to use `arctan` from -pi to pi, but with `arctan2(1,1/x)` it gave the same graphic as the text book. Please, feel free to apply any corrections using arctan and getting the same results

Comment: @dustin Could you explain from were you took arctan(x)=arctan2(1,1/x)? Because the common practice is to use arctan(x) and sum `2pi` to the negative results

Comment: @SaulloCastro a physicists suggested `1, 1 / x` usage in `arctan2`

Comment: @dustin It would be nice to include a reference to this in the question or in the answer

Comment: @SaulloCastro a reference to what?

Comment: @dustin a reference to proof that arctan(x)=arctan2(1,1/x)

Comment: @SaulloCastro I added what he said but it isn't a proof just a conjecture.

Comment: @SaulloCastro - Not a proof, but in Maple 15 simplifying the expression `arctan(1, 1/x)` gives `arctan(x)` for non-negative numbers, and `arctan(x) + π` for negative numbers.

Comment: @Yay295 really appreciate your comment. Even edited the answer to include it

Comment: @Yay295 could you please provide a link to this documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Given x and y coordinates, the following code will evaluate correctly the angle (assuming the angle is measured from the x-axis and counter-clockwise) between the range 0 to 2pi. It just sums 2pi if the output of arctan2 is negative in a simple and effective manner.

```
import numpy as np
np.arctan2(y,x) + -1*(np.sign(np.arctan2(y,x))-1)*np.pi
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35125846)