# numpy array - replace certain values

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have yet to get my head around numpy array referencing.

I have arrays where the first 2 columns will always have some negative values that are necessary and the remaining columns need to have their negative values substituted with 0s. I understand that there are various ways [to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335090/numpy-replace-negative-values-in-array). The part that's baffling me is how to combine one of these methods with only doing it for the columns past 2.

Example array:

```
[[x, y, flow, element1, element2, element3] [x, y, flow, element1, element2, element3] [x, y, flow, element1, element2, element3]]
```

Desired result would be that for the whole array, any of the values that are negative are replaced with 0 unless they are x or y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to `clip` subsets of the arrays.

something like this:

```
a[2:].clip(0, None)
```

You could do this a couple of ways. One would be in a for loop:

```
for list in list_of_lists:
    list[2:] = list[2:].clip(0, None)
```

Or, using `[:, 2:]` which references your list of lists (`:`), and then all sublists of that (`2:`).

The result is basically what Joe Kingston has suggested:

```
list[:, 2:] = list[:, 2:].clip(0, None)
```

Comment: You'll need to either clip in-place or assign the values back to the array. E.g. `a[:,2:].clip(0, None, a[:,2:])` or `a[:, 2:] = a[:,2:].clip(0, None)`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want:

```
subset = array[:, 2:]
subset[subset < 0] = 0
```

or as a rather unreadable one-liner:

```
array[:, 2:][array[:, 2:] < 0] = 0
```

As a more complete example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 5))
print array

# Note that "subset" is a view, so modifying it modifies "array"
subset = array[:, 2:]
subset[subset < 0] = 0

print array
```