# Extract positive and negative values from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array called `A`:

```
A = np.array([[-1, 2, -3],
              [4, -5, 6],
              [-7, 8, -9]])
```

Now I want to extract positive and negative parts and save them in two new arrays like:

```
B = np.array([[0, 2, 0],
              [4, 0, 6],
              [0, 8, 0]])
```

for positive parts and

```
C = np.array([[-1, 0, -3],
              [0, -5, 0],
              [-7, 0, -9]])
```

for negative parts.

Could you please guide me how to get arrays `B` and `C` from array `A` in Python 3.6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy replace negative values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335090/numpy-replace-negative-values-in-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The solution

Use two [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)s to replace the values below zero and above zero:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[-1, 2, -3], [4, -5, 6], [-7, 8, -9]])
>>> B = np.where(A > 0, A, 0)
>>> C = np.where(A < 0, A, 0)
>>> B
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 8, 0]])
>>> C
array([[-1,  0, -3],
       [ 0, -5,  0],
       [-7,  0, -9]])
```

### The explanation

The three argument form of `np.where` broadcasts the arguments, the first and second already have the same shape `(3, 3)` but the `0` will be broadcasted to:

```
>>> Ag0_bc, B_bc, zero_bc = np.broadcast_arrays(A > 0, A, 0)
>>> Ag0_bc
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> zero_bc
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Then `np.where` will create a new array and fill each element in the new array with the corresponding element from the second argument (`A`) if the element in the first argument (`A > 0`) is `True` and take the element from the third argument `0` in case it's `False`.