# Ambiguous Error using clip, where to replace negative numbers with zero

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace negative values in a multidimensional array with zeros.

I've been trying suggestions here: [How to transform negative elements to zero without a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391843/how-to-transform-negative-elements-to-zero-without-a-loop)

I get "the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous errors."

This is the array (a):

```
[ [  77.23262142  111.08317492  105.03704946   29.28612695   29.11454024
   10.07763987  -28.43527526  -41.68250773  -60.18250773  -73.61424205
-71.9592605   -74.25815349  -72.67697268  -61.01276604]
[ 346.32487234  346.35439263  332.45955869  305.13299042  253.4706288
 254.19387603  174.91896828  162.73446644  111.50014909   76.9614037
34.36361773  -25.55151142  -47.37254463  -57.63638227  -63.009076
-78.0385963   -56.38361475]
[ 217.45402363  172.89867308  158.19756607  159.74184651  142.31195721
153.54258452  158.28612695  133.56841478  159.88391293  131.50383913
152.97800887   60.40789817   93.2104812    71.13852548    2.02782437
-20.78398375  -52.2692236   -70.02752618  -76.46110552  -79.26184353
-68.36516456]
[ 268.77690186  246.15144061  199.3211823   229.61269522  175.28797197
219.35992769  194.95771367  197.6809609   202.8008871   194.34332252
201.19018599  140.29719706  164.36177271  100.68280592   96.90789817
62.38944799   19.59424503  -20.86700958  -47.14745238  -69.58472176
-74.28767379  -78.07365165  -89.37254463  -92.21387305]
[ 223.63668046  220.66804577  238.79535204  217.27690186  198.98723396
197.60162511  164.90605315  146.49461404  153.33225241  142.98538894
130.63852548  179.9706288   149.22708636  162.03704946  169.48723396
136.3008871   110.43926348   57.75845168   31.57579485  -25.19173283
-24.65667748  -56.25077342  -74.39652987  -78.69173283  -73.14745238
-71.89468486]
[ 205.54442954  236.53335942  220.39682806  210.16989079  163.2307764
177.45955869  161.84516754  161.58501994  186.19941109  174.29535204
201.33225241  211.2805919   193.33040739  206.32671736  190.24369153
160.91158821  164.12007529  125.9411085   113.82487234   83.49461404
35.88760297   -3.9795557   -21.52014611  -42.49800589  -62.73232323
-92.21387305  -78.48509076  -92.409445  ]
[ 269.6606657   280.96509374  273.66620075  272.83040739  252.07579485
263.64406053  272.48723396  257.49645906  240.12561035  250.14406053
241.07579485  237.02597935  226.8507026   206.71417123  173.3507026
174.34332252  188.71601625  149.40974319  191.18834097  153.50937418
113.72155131  131.25291662   89.53889448   68.59609005   41.67727086
10.68280592  -26.89283984  -35.4389653   -53.76368855  -61.76553356
-50.72494316]]
```

I've tried:

```
b = np.clip(a,0, 5000)
b = a.clip(min=0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the fact that it's an array of arrays, not just an array, may mean the answer has to be slightly changed.

Comment: do you mean change the question for an array of arrays?

Comment: What I mean is, the question you linked to was for a single dimensional array - and you have a two dimensional array. So the answers for his case will need to be modified to work for your case. (Not having numpy I can't say in what way)

Comment: What didn't work with `b = np.clip(a,0, 5000)`?

Comment: `a = np.random((5,6,7,8)) - 0.5; b = a.clip(min=0)` works fine for me...

Comment: Bi Rico answered below, explaining why the above do not work with my situation of an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it really helps when you ask a question if you can post a working example that demonstrates your issue. Without that we're left to guess.

It seems that maybe you're using an array of arrays instead of a multidimensional array. For example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(3)

# Make an array of arrays
arrayOfArrays = np.empty(4, dtype=object)
arrayOfArrays.fill(data)
print arrayOfArrays
# [[0 1 2] [0 1 2] [0 1 2] [0 1 2]]

# Make a 2d array
array2d = np.empty((4, 3), dtype=int)
array2d[:] = data
print array2d
# [[0 1 2]
#  [0 1 2]
#  [0 1 2]
#  [0 1 2]]

# You can clip an ndarray of any dimenssion
array2d.clip(1)

# But clipping an array of arrays gives the error you describe
arrayOfArrays.clip(1)
# ValueError                                
# Traceback (most recent call last) <module>()
#      17 
#      18 # This will fail
#
# ---> 19 arrayOfArrays.clip(1)
#
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If you are in fact using an array of arrays, an array with dtype object, than try using a multidimensional array instead. arrays of dtype object are prone to all types of issues, I generally try to avoid them. You can tell whether you're using an array with dtype object by checking the shape and dtype like bellow:

```
print array2d.dtype
print array2d.shape
# int32
# (4, 3)

print arrayOfArrays.dtype
print arrayOfArrays.shape
# object
# (4,)
```

Of course in this case you could just loop over the outer array and call clip on each of the inner arrays.

```
for i in range(len(arrayOfArrays)):
    arrayOfArrays[i].clip(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation and you gave me a lot of options as well as good advice moving forward. I battle the array of arrays a lot with what I am doing. Will have to learn to avoid better in the future. For now, I used your final suggestion and set up a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try just setting the negative values to zero:

```
a[a<0] = 0
```

Comment: sorry, did not work, I got the same error, see answer above.  thanks.