# Trying to make else if statements with np.min

Tags: python, numpy

```
def q3(a1:np.ndarray, a2:np.ndarray):
    e =  np.add(a1, a2)
    f = np.add(a1, a2)
    if [np.min(f) < 0] == 0:
      return 0
    else:
      return np.min(e)
```

I get the adding of these and getting the minimum but if the minimum of f is negative should be 0.

Comment: im just confused about how to make an if-else state so one can return to e if its positive min and if a negative min should equal 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform negative elements to zero without a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391843/how-to-transform-negative-elements-to-zero-without-a-loop)

Comment: What is `f` in `return f`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
def q3(a1:np.ndarray, a2:np.ndarray):
    e =  np.add(a1, a2)
    e_min = np.min(e)
    print(e)
    if e_min > 0:
        return e_min
    else:
        return 0
```

You may not need f in this case, just store the minimum of e in a variable. You can choose to print e or not depending on whether you need to display the list of sums.